# searching in UITableView, but keep each section with a result

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

When I look at this table for a product, I force myself to search by product name search.
Within this list, you will find the name, image, product description and thumb.
See the code below:

```
-(void) lookinfor
{
    NSString *searchText        = search_bar.text;
    NSMutableArray *searchArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    dict_produtos               = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


    for (NSDictionary *dictionary in array_sections)
    {
        NSArray *array = [dictionary valueForKey:@"products"];
        [searchArray addObjectsFromArray:array];
    }

    for (NSDictionary *dicts in searchArray)
    {
        NSString *sTemp = [dicts objectForKey:@"name"];

        NSRange titleResultsRange = [sTemp rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        if (titleResultsRange.length != 0)
        {
            [dict_produtos setObject:sTemp forKey:@"name"];
            [dict_produtos setObject:[dicts objectForKey:@"thumb"] forKey:@"thumb"];
            [dict_produtos setObject:[dicts objectForKey:@"image"] forKey:@"image"];
            [dict_produtos setObject:[dicts objectForKey:@"description"] forKey:@"description"];
        }
    }
    searchArray = nil;
}
```

I get the whole list back perfectly, ie, looking for the name and get the thumb to enter the cell of the table, perfect, that's what I need..

So, when counting the lines of the section, only returns 1 line (name, image, thumb and description). So only returns 1 product.

That was the only solution I found to keep all the data together

For this reason I could not keep the sections while im searching and moreover, appears only 1 result (the others do not appear, even having found more than 1 record)
Does anyone have a better solution for this?

Thanks for all help!